# How do I install nodejs as an asset upload web service to work with my wordpress setup

Tags: wordpress, web-services, node.js

I have a Wordpress setup and my client needs users to upload large image and video files into the media library using a front-end form - NOT the wp backend.

I was thinking using something like express with a package like formidable

I want to know if it is possible to create an internal service on my vps server that wordpress could talk to.

Specifically, I want to know:

1. How do I hit an external url like api.domain.com/uploads and send wordpress data through to that server
2. How do I get the processed output back into wordpress and then save it

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on retrieving information from an external source through node.js & PHP

http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/

With that said, I would personally create a shortcode by plugin design or create a theme template for this particular Form setup and with a combination of PHP, JS, Jquery, and various functions

```
if(is_page("page_name")) {
    /*custom functions that will connect externally*/
    wp_insert_comment($array_of_values);  //pass values through standard PHP methods (global variables, etc)
}
```

Reference:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_comment

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Nested_Loops

Comment: How can I use `is_page`? My server file in node will be called `server.js` or `app.js`. Won't be a php file and it will be running inside a node process. How do I hit that custom end point?

Comment: Considering wordpress is a PHP site, don't you think you would need to have a PHP front end for it to interact with Node.JS?  And I would think you would use some type of Javascript on the PHP end in order to communicate and retrieve information whether it is through AJAX or other POST types.  Am I not understanding your question?